# rails object expected got string in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have this:

```
<%= f.association :gestor, selected: current_usuario.gestor_id, label_method: :descricao, value: current_usuario.gestor_id, disabled: true %>
```

My controller:

```
   def create
    @usuario = Usuario.new(usuario_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @usuario.save
        format.html { redirect_to controle_usuarios_path, notice: 'Usuario was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @usuario }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
(...)
    def usuario_params
          params.require(:usuario).permit(:cpf, :usuario_pai, :gestor_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :agente_id, :perfil_id)
        end
```

And console:

```
Processing by ControleUsuariosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xnMQOvRLO3cCrq/l5KSSG0qB3Pc8S4wtSgs4PTCTkaJ5kLLwMD73s/4TeBWYYbvmBKzvBca4T0eMT9F9UQo/Ew==", "usuario"=>{"usuario_pai"=>"admin@mail.com", "agente_id"=>"2", "cpf"=>"111.111.111-11", "email"=>"xxx@xxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "perfil_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Criar Usuario"}
```

The params gestor_id don't come, why? The error is this:

Usuario(#70271925151780) expected, got String(#3432540)

Comment: I guess you don't get `gestor_id` in the params simply because the select box is set as disabled (the `disabled => true` option). Disabled form tags do NOT pass value on form submit. Or are you enabling it later using Javascript?

Comment: WOW, I removed the disabled: true, and the params gestor_id submitted, but I got same error: Usuario(#48266120) expected, got String(#6291560) =/

Comment: So I guess it is two unrelated errors (missing attribute and the error you describe). The missing attribute is already solved (by enabling the select again) but to correct the other error, we'd need you to point us to the line in your code where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: The error is exactly in def create @usuario = Usuario.new(usuario_params)

Comment: Can you post a few more lines from the error stack trace?

Comment: @BoraMa I update my question and add all method create

Comment: Thanks but still the exact location of the error is unclear to me. If you can, please post the [stack trace](http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace?view=asciicast).

Comment: @BoraMa it is this: https://gist.github.com/eltonsantos/b950ab57af8c554147fc

Comment: OK, from the stack trace it is clear ([line 4](https://gist.github.com/eltonsantos/b950ab57af8c554147fc#file-tmp-L4)) that you are putting a string (email) into the `usario_pai` parameter whereas it expects an associated object (user).

Comment: Yep, but I need this, I need that usuario_pai to be a string, because I need get email, because this I put belongs_to :usuario_pai, class_name: "Usuario", foreign_key: 'usuario_pai' on my model

Comment: Besides, I remove usuario_pai for test, but the error continue

Comment: No, again, as you stated below in a comment, table `usuarios`  has an `usuario_pai` column **of type integer**, as you say, it's a `belongs_to` association and now you are trying to set it a string (email).  That's the meaning of the error. I don't believe the error is the same even when you remove the `usuario_pai` parameter. Please post another stack trace to prove.

Comment: @BoraMa , So, Usuario was created successfully, but I had remove belongs_to :usuario_pai, class_name: "Usuario", foreign_key: 'usuario_pai'. I can't do it =( I need take usuario_pai.email

Comment: Please reformulate, specify better what you need to achieve, perhaps as another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is looking for `gester_id` and you are passing in `gester` as the param so it is being removed. Try changing it in your view to `gester_id` or in your params filter to `gester`.

Comment: But I dont have gestor_id, I have just gestor. In my columns, in my tables, in my params. And I try, and got this error: association not found

Comment: @EltonSantos it looks like you are returning a `current_usuario.gestor_id` and could you show your tables?

Comment: Usuario table is: cpf character varying(14), gestor_id integer, usuario_pai integer, admin boolean, agente_id integer, perfil_id integer.
Gestor table is: id and descricao. User belongs_to gestor, Gestor has_many usuarios